# Flutter range error not in inclusive range

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a button, which is changing bool value, but when i click button so fast in row then it throw this error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 list of texts and i wanted it to generate one of them when bool value was true or false. So I use this code

```
or ? truths[Random().nextInt(truths.length - 1)] : dares[Random().nextInt(dares.length - 1)]
```

insted of this code

```
or ? truths[Random().nextInt(truths.length)] : dares[Random().nextInt(dares.length)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are chaning some list on that page. Maybe based on that bool value that is changed when you are pressing the button.

Comment: Yeah bro there was problem in lists, so i found a solution and shared it below in answers. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, nice that you found it! Sorry, didn't see your extra post. Seems they posted same time :-S